# Android textview contents not refreshing upon callback

Tags: java, android, callback, textview

I am trying to refresh the content in text view upon call back. In my onCreateView() when I  first load the fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_expense,container,false);
    total = 0;
    // some logic to get the total
    txtTotal.setText(String.valueOf(total));
    return v;
}
```

From first fragment I set the call back when button on click go to second fragment:

```
// set call back
addFragment.setTransactionListCallBack(ExpenseActivity.this);
```

Then when finish updating and retrieve in second fragment using async task, I pass back the updated results:

```
if(mcallback != null){
   mcallback.callback(GetMonthlyTransactionAsyncTask.allTransaction);
}
```

Then I perform some insert into database, but before I return I am pulling the data again so I will pass back the updated one. In my callback in first fragment:

```
 @Override
public void callback(ArrayList<Transaction> list)
{
    // logic to sum up the total
    Log.d("UPDATED TOTAL", String.valueOf(total));
    txtTotal.setText(String.valueOf(total));
}
```

The call back is working perfectly as I did printed out the log to check the before update (inside onCreateView) and after update (inside callback), the value printed out is correct. So I guess there is not a need to show the code.

The problem now is inside my callback in first fragment, the updated value I printed out in Log is correct which is the updated one, but not the content displayed in the text view. The text view is still stuck with the old value.

Any ideas how to refresh the textview content upon call back?

Comment: Please post more code, it's hard to help you without seeing more of your class.  For example, where are you changing the value of total to be different?

Comment: @parkgrrr it is in the 3rd block of code I just edited. The callback is working perfectly and there is no issue with that since I managed to printed out the correct value inside the callback in first fragment. The problem now is the textview is still stuck with the old value

Answer (score 0):

`invalidate()` must be called from a UI thread. To call from a non-UI thread, call `postInvalidate()`

```
@Override
public void callback(ArrayList<Transaction> list)
{
    // logic to sum up the total
    Log.d("UPDATED TOTAL", String.valueOf(total));
    txtTotal.setText(String.valueOf(total));
    txtTotal.postInvalidate();
}
```

Also, check if there is a textview with the same id.

Answer (score -1):

You may be trying to set the textview on a different thread if asynctask is involved, try setting the text view on the UI thread:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
             @Override
                 public void run() {
                   txtTotal.setText(String.valueOf(total));
         }
     });
```

Edit: also try `txtTotal.invalidate()` after you set text.

Comment: So I put this piece of code inside the callback or?

Comment: Nope the textview is still stuck with the old value. But the printed log is showing the update value :(

Comment: The strange thing is, it did went into the run() with the correct value printed out in log. However, the content in textview is not updating at all

Comment: Hey do you have any ideas?

Comment: It's hard for me to offer any other suggestions without being able to see more code or debug it myself. It is strange you get the correct value with your log statement but not in the text view. Could you post more details of the async task? Could it be that you are setting text in the callback before some async operation comes back, or the total operation is finished?

Comment: To debug I would maybe try creating another empty text view in the activity, and populate txtTotal with the initial value, and try populating the separate text view with the callback total to see if it populates at all.